# How to activate "Log Off" option in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, operating-system, logoff

Recently We are using Windows Server 2016, but there is no option "Log off' like in older version of OS, Only there are "Disconnect", "Shutdown" and "Restart" option.

I would like to activate Logoff so the resources will be free at eod.

Thanks,
Laxmi Lal Menaria

Comment: There is if you right-click the start menu. It's not visible in the "normal" start menu options, or it's disabled by GPO (or something).

Answer (score 1):

You're clicking the power button in Start.

You need to click the user account icon in Start to find the Sign Out option.